# How to enable User able to see a custom entity record having N:N relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a custom entity `Project`, which is having a many to many relationship with `User` entity.My requirement is when an `User` is added to a `Project` he/she only can see that project.

To do that I have tried to add a custom Plugin which will share the `Project` record to added `User`, in update message of `Project` entity. But plugin not firing.

Is there any other way to do that? Please help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the step of your plugin at `Associate` message (and eventually `Disassociate` is you want to manage also when a `Project` record is removed from a `User`) not the `Update` one.

When a record is linked with a `1:N` or `N:N` relationship the record doesn't get updated.

The `Associate` message needs to be registered against all entities (leaving empty or set to `none` the Primary Entity field inside Plugin Registration Tool)

If you use the Developer Toolkit you can find a tutorial to register on `Associate` message here:

http://zhongchenzhou.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/create-plug-in-for-message-with-no-primary-entity-associated-using-dynamics-crm-2011-developer-toolkit/

Read also this post that explains how to check the entities that triggered the plugin:

http://orwin.ca/2011/07/05/crm-2011-plugin-triggering-off-associate-message/

Comment: Hi Guido, thnx 4 ur quick reply. I am using MS developers tool kit. there is no `Associate` message